# Mark dates within several date ranges

Tags: r

I'm trying to mark all dates, which fall within several ranges in a different table.

The `events` table among other variables contains `start_date` and `end_date` of events:

```
events <- tibble(
  name = c("Event A", "Event B"),
  start_date = as.Date(c("2021-10-17", "2021-02-19")),
  end_date = as.Date(c("2021-10-19", "2021-02-10"))
)
```

The `date_info` table contains `date`, `statistic` and `value` information in the long format for all days of the year:

```
date_info <- tibble(
  date = as.Date(c("2021-10-16", "2021-10-16", "2021-10-17", "2021-10-17")),
  statistic = c("var1", "var2", "var1", "var2"),
  value = c(10, 54, 23, 34)
)
```

I need to make a new column in `date_info` to mark dates which fall within any date range of `events`.

I've tried the approach below, but it works only if there is one event in `events`

```
library(tidyverse)

date_info %>% 
  mutate(in_range = if_else(date < events$start_date | date > events$end_date, FALSE, TRUE))
```

I thought about creating a `date_range` vector in `events` such that code below can be used to mark the dates:

```
library(tidyverse)

date_info %>%
mutate(in_range = if_else(date %in% events$date_range, TRUE, FALSE))
```

However I'm not sure that this is the best approach. Additionally I'm not sure how to get such date range as `seq()` works on a single start/end date pair rather than a vector.

Comment: Does it need to simply set a boolean to true if it falls into any of the ranges, or specify which range it falls into? Also, posting a small sample of code to create the data you're working with is very helpful.

Comment: It simply needs to set a boolean to true if it falls within any date range. Knowing which range it is in, isn't necessary @geoff

Comment: If you write code to generate dfs of the two tables you shared I'll write the answer.

Comment: @geoff updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done as a range-based or non-equi join. Unfortunately, `dplyr` alone cannot do it, but one of the following should work fine.

The code below assigns the particular `events$name` to each row, not just an "in range" indicator. It's not hard to simplify that with `in_range = !is.na(name)` or similar.

### fuzzyjoin

```r
# library(fuzzyjoin)
date_info %>%
  fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(events,
    by = c(date = "start_date", date = "end_date"),
    match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`))
# # A tibble: 4 x 6
#   date       statistic value name    start_date end_date  
#   <date>     <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   <date>     <date>    
# 1 2021-10-16 var1         10 NA      NA         NA        
# 2 2021-10-16 var2         54 NA      NA         NA        
# 3 2021-10-17 var1         23 Event A 2021-10-17 2021-10-19
# 4 2021-10-17 var2         34 Event A 2021-10-17 2021-10-19
```

### sqldf

```r
# library(sqldf)
sqldf::sqldf("
  select t1.*, t2.name
  from date_info t1
    left join events t2 on t1.date between t2.start_date and t2.end_date")
#         date statistic value    name
# 1 2021-10-16      var1    10    <NA>
# 2 2021-10-16      var2    54    <NA>
# 3 2021-10-17      var1    23 Event A
# 4 2021-10-17      var2    34 Event A
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
date_info_DT <- as.data.table(date_info)
events_DT <- as.data.table(events)
date_info_DT[events_DT, name := i.name,
             on = .(date >= start_date, date <= end_date)][]
#          date statistic value    name
#        <Date>    <char> <num>  <char>
# 1: 2021-10-16      var1    10    <NA>
# 2: 2021-10-16      var2    54    <NA>
# 3: 2021-10-17      var1    23 Event A
# 4: 2021-10-17      var2    34 Event A
```

(There's also `data.table::foverlaps`, which requires the second `data.table` to be `key`ed.)

Another option, a bit simpler (not requiring class-changes):

```r
date_info %>%
  mutate(in_range = data.table::inrange(date, events$start_date, events$end_date))
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   date       statistic value in_range
#   <date>     <chr>     <dbl>    <lgl>
# 1 2021-10-16 var1         10    FALSE
# 2 2021-10-16 var2         54    FALSE
# 3 2021-10-17 var1         23     TRUE 
# 4 2021-10-17 var2         34     TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `map` from the `purrr` package that should work. It could be more concise but I made it very explicit so it's not overwhelming if you're not familiar with the syntax.

```
date_info |> 
  mutate(
    in_range_n = map_dbl(date, .f = function(date){
      filter(events, start_date <= date, end_date >= date) |> 
        nrow()
      }),
    in_range = in_range_n > 0
    ) |> 
  select(-in_range_n)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  date       statistic value in_range
  <date>     <chr>     <dbl> <lgl>   
1 2021-10-16 var1         10 FALSE   
2 2021-10-16 var2         54 FALSE   
3 2021-10-17 var1         23 TRUE    
4 2021-10-17 var2         34 TRUE
```

Let me know if I misunderstood the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Using base r

```
date_info$in_range <- sapply(date_info$date, function(date){
  any(date >= events$start_date & date <= events$end_date)
  })
```

gives

```
  date       statistic value in_range
  <date>     <chr>     <dbl> <lgl>   
1 2021-10-16 var1         10 FALSE   
2 2021-10-16 var2         54 FALSE   
3 2021-10-17 var1         23 TRUE    
4 2021-10-17 var2         34 TRUE
```